# Linq use value from select new to calculate another field

Tags: linq

Is it possible to do the following in linq, where in my `select new` I use the value from `TotalOrderItems` as part of the calculation for `TotalInStockItems`?

```
var Order = (from o in orderItems
             select new ShippingOrder { OrderId = orderItems.OrderId
                                        TotalOrderItems = orderItems.GroupBy(x => x.Sku).Count(),
                                        TotalInStockItems = TotalOrderItems - orderItems.Where(x => x.InStock =='F').GroupBy(x => x.Sku).Count(),
                                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: You may need to review the example in your question. It does not look complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the [let clause (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) to store the value for use later in the query

```
(from o in orderItems
 let totalOrderItems = orderItems.GroupBy(x => x.Sku).Count()
 select new ShippingOrder { 
     OrderId = o.OrderId
     TotalOrderItems = totalOrderItems,
     TotalInStockItems = totalOrderItems - orderItems.Where(x => x.InStock =='F').GroupBy(x => x.Sku).Count(),
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. Did not know about `let`. Thanks!